# Specifying times for Wait Periods in Journey Builder using Workflow Document Format

Tags: journeybuilder, marketing-cloud

In the [Workflow Document Format](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/workflow-format/getting-started.html) I note we can define what time an activity is fired after a [Wait Period](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/#WaitPeriod).

For Activity Objects with a `wait` type, you can define values for a `specifiedTime` and `timeZoneId` in the `configurationArguments` object as per the example below:

```
  {
     "id":"51e1f568-0867-415a-ad8b-016a7980519e",
     "key":"cad2a0f0-0df6-daf4-7b49-f8e2287abf2e",
     "name":"",
     "type":"Wait",
     "outcomes":[
        {
           "key":"40cd2874-f16e-71d2-1a81-dfc6b40c2d6d",
           "arguments":{ },
           "metaData":{ }
        }
     ],
     "arguments":{ },
     "configurationArguments":{
        "waitDuration":1,
        "waitUnit":"Days",
        "specifiedTime":null,
        "timeZoneId":76
     },
     "metaData":{ }
  }
```

(I retrieved the example above by looking at the response that I get from the [getInteractionById](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/getInteractionById.html) method).

Please can someone enlighten me how we can use these `specifiedTime` and `timeZoneId` key-value pairs? I'm assuming that if I want to send emails at 2pm in the afternoon (when the open rate is typically higher), then I can set these values here. Is that correct? If so, what format does the date need to be in and what are the respective integers for different [tz time zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're looking for is not currently supported.  However, I will log this as a request for a new feature that we may be able to look into for future development.

The wait time that you specify in that scenario is waiting a specific amount of time after the previously completed trigger/activity, which is different from what you're looking for, which would be to wait until a specific time/date.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for confirming however the [documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-AU/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/#WaitPeriod) explains this can be done: '*You can also set the time of day the an activity launches and the time zone in which customers reside with this option.*' I assume this feature was removed and the documentation was never updated. Is that correct?

Comment: The [code@ documentation](http://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/interaction-components/waits.html) also explains this time feature: '*Duration + Time: Defines the amount of time between the previous Interaction Component and the subsequent action days only, plus waiting until a specific time on that particular day to permit the subsequent action beginning.*'

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this functionality is now supported, according to the [Wait Format documentation](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/workflow-format/activity-formats/wait.html) that was updated earlier this month. This updated page now contains a list of supported time zones and updated name/value pairs. (I'm assuming that if documentation is published publicly, then the functionality is available for use).

The time and time zone can't be configured in the Interaction Canvas interface yet, but in the meantime it appears that it's possible to define these properties in a Wait Activity object using WDF.

I've updated an Interaction with the following Wait Activity and it updated successfully:

```
{
   "key":"best-send-time",
   "name":"Optimised open rate time",
   "type":"Wait",
   "outcomes":[
      {
         "key":"wait-outcome-to-send-email",
         "next":"send-reminder-email"
      }
   ],
   "configurationArguments":{
      "waitDuration":2,
      "waitUnit":"days",
      "specificTime":"14:00",
      "timeZone":"E. Australia Standard Time"
   }
}
```

A few notes and assumptions though, regarding the documentation for the benefit of others who want to use this functionality:

1. The JSON payload example provided in the documentation uses `specifiedTime` instead of `specificTime`. `specifiedTime` was used in v0.5 and is now deprecated. You should use `specificTime`.
2. I'm assuming that the `specificTime` is only applicable if the `waitUnit` has value of days, weeks or months. It's not clear from the documentation if this is the case.
3. I note that there is a new `waitForEventKey` name/value pair added to a Wait Activity object — while I assume this is reserved for future use, it does indicate the direction of Wait Activities. That would be really handy to get a Wait Period to wait for an Event to be fired. Perhaps we'll see this support soon!