# Wait Until - Maximum Time in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I would like please to know what's the maximum time set for a "Wait Until" activity.
Can I put 24 months in a "Wait Until" activity? Will records stay in the Journey for that time?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Dunno if [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58414/specifying-times-for-wait-periods-in-journey-builder-using-workflow-document-for) is related but it's worth a look.

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson thanks a lot for your response. I mean when you configure the Wait Until Activity in the Journey, you can select (Set maximum wait time): minutes, hours, days, weeks and months. My question is if 24 months will be available or it might give an error (not in the activation, but in the "life" of the records inserted)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a wait for 24 months, but I would consider it not to be best practice. The logical enforced maximum is 999 months.  It might make more sense to have a separate journey or automation that fires 24 months down the road and picks up where it left off.

Just seems like too much risk for little reward - that data/process would have to endure 2 years of application updates (of which there are 8-10 a year), new journey versions (which don't bring over subscribers from other journeys).

Once a journey starts, it locks existing subscribers into that flow. If you wanted to edit anything about the logic in that 2 year period, it wouldn't affect the subscribers sitting in that wait step.